# Datacap 9.0.0.2 FastDoc issue making a field read-only

Tags: ibm-datacap

I have developed an application on Datacap 9.0.0.2.

I need to make a certain field in my application to be a read only field.  I used FastDoc to run my application.  I tried everything and I succeeded in making this field a read-only field on (Datacap desktop) and (web-admin client) but then I failed to make this field read-only on FastDoc.

How can I make this field read-only with FastDoc?

Answer (score 0):

The read-only mechanism you reference (Field variable 'ReadOnly' = 1) is only available, and only operates in the VeriFine web client & Datacap Desktop thick client.

You will likely need to raise an enhancement request to have this compatible with FastDoc.

It's possible to 'hack' around the problem by using Validation rules that will always populate the initial 'read-only' value, however i suppose this largely depends on your use-case.

IBM Content Navigator for Datacap (Datacap - Navigator) supports read-only mechanism via the use of EDS (External Data Services).